# Validation working on edit but template missing error on Create Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.1.4 and ruby 2.1.2. I am new on Ruby on Rails Programming. I got template missing error on validating form. Same code is working for edit but is showing this error on create new post. Here is my code for creating/editing post for a blog(my first test RoR app).

The controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your Post was saved"
    else
        render new
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Post updated successfully"
    else
        render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been deleted"
  end
end
```

The Model::

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :title, :length => { :minimum => 2}
  # validates :title, :uniqueness => true
  validates :title, :uniqueness => { :message => "Already Taken"}
end
```

The view files::

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a new post</h1>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>

  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <h2>Errors:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %> <br />
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %> <br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %> <br />
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add a New Post" %> <br />
  </p>

<% end %>
```

And edit.html.erb

```
 <h1>Edit Posts</h1>
 <%= form_for @post do |f| %>

 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
   <h2>Errors:</h2>
<ul>
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br />
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit "Update Post" %><br />
</p>

<% end %>
```

Validation is running successfully on editing post. But problem is it is showing following error on creating new post::

```
  Template is missing
  Missing partial posts/_post with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/sandesh/blog/app/views"
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think there is some problem while you posted your `edit.html.erb` in question. Check it once

Comment: It seems your action redirecting to index action and in the `posts/index.html.erb` you have mentioned a `render partial: 'post'`. Can you post the code of your index.html.erb here?

Comment: Not related, but there should be `render :new`, not `render new`. UPDATE: Actually, I think this is the problem here. I'll post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in here:

```
render new
```

It is executing `new` method which returns a new instance of post, so it reads as:

```
render Post.new
```

When render get a model it tries to render a partial for it, so it is looking for `_post` partial view, which obviously doesn't exist. What you need is:

```
render :new
```